# Why is this a negative frequency?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction, conventions, frequency

In general, i have noticed that i have simple accepted the fact that $$\psi = e^{i(kx-wt)}$$ represents a positive frequency, and $$\psi = e^{i(kx+wt)}$$ represents a negative frequency.

After a time of wondering, i realized i have no idea why, and was just repeating what i have read. I mean, if the wave is propagating to right direction, i can undernstand that $\psi = e^{i(kx+wt)}$ is negative frequency since $$\delta \phi = \delta (kx+wt) = 0 \\ k \delta x + w \delta t =0 \\ \frac{\delta x}{\delta t} = -w/k \\ \delta x >0, \delta t >0 \implies w < 0$$

BUT, this wave can as well describy a wave function propagating to the left (assume please that right x is positive). So why, instead of assuming the most simply idead that we have a wave propagating to left, we instead say this represents a negative frequency?

The question has arised when i was doing this exercise: "Show that $\psi(x,-t)^{\star}$ represents a positive frequency wave".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naming of positive and negative frequency is a convention related to your Fourier transform conventions. In quantum mechanics, a more physical distinction is between positive and negative *energy* states (which, of course, are related to positive and negative frequencies by $E=\hbar \omega$). Given a Hamiltonian $H$, positive energy states are eigenstates with positive energy eigenvalues, and negative energy states are eigenstates with negative energy eigenvalues.

It's also important to note that there there are two different concepts.

- To distinguish positive and negative energies, we look at the sign of $\omega$ in $e^{\pm i \omega t}$.
- To distinguish left and right moving waves, we look at the *relative sign* between $\omega$ and $k$ in the expression $e^{\pm i(\omega t \pm k x)}$.

Concretely, there are $4$ cases.

1. **Positive energy, right moving** $\propto e^{-i \omega t + i k x}$
2. **Positive energy, left moving** $\propto e^{-i \omega t - i k x}$
3. **Negative energy, right moving** $\propto e^{i \omega t - i k x}$
4. **Negative energy, left moving** $\propto e^{i \omega t + i k x}$